# Repeat number of galleries without duplicating code for gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a free jquery gallery and I want to make as many galleries as I want on the page. Problem is how the javascript is written will require to duplicate and rename, the code. Here's what the javascript that renders the gallery looks like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var slideShow = $('#slideShow'),
        ul = slideShow.find('ul'),
        li = ul.find('li'),
        cnt = li.length;

    // As the images are positioned absolutely, the last image will be shown on top.
    // This is why we force them in the correct order by assigning z-indexes:

    updateZindex();

    if($.support.transform){

        // Modern browsers with support for css3 transformations

        li.find('img').css('rotate',function(i){
            // Rotating the images counterclockwise
            return (-90*i) + 'deg';
        });

        // Binding a custom event. the direction and degrees parameters
        // are passed when the event is triggered later on in the code.

        slideShow.bind('rotateContainer',function(e,direction,degrees){

            // Enlarging the slideshow and photo:

            slideShow.animate({
                width       : 510,
                height      : 510,
                marginTop   : 0,
                marginLeft  : 0
            },'fast',function(){

                if(direction == 'next'){

                    // Moving the topmost image containing Li at
                    // the bottom after a fadeOut animation

                    $('li:first').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                        $(this).remove().appendTo(ul).show();
                        updateZindex();
                    });
                }
                else {

                    // Showing the bottomost Li element on top 
                    // with a fade in animation. Notice that we are
                    // updating the z-indexes.

                    var liLast = $('li:last').hide().remove().prependTo(ul);
                    updateZindex();
                    liLast.fadeIn('slow');
                }

                // Rotating the slideShow. css('rotate') gives us the
                // current rotation in radians. We are converting it to
                // degress so we can add 90 or -90 to rotate it to its new value.

                slideShow.animate({             
                    rotate:Math.round($.rotate.radToDeg(slideShow.css('rotate'))+degrees) + 'deg'
                },'slow').animate({
                    width       : 490,
                    height      : 490,
                    marginTop   : 10,
                    marginLeft  : 10
                },'fast');
            });
        });

        // By triggering the custom events below, we can 
        // show the previous / next images in the slideshow.

        slideShow.bind('showNext',function(){
            slideShow.trigger('rotateContainer',['next',90]);
        });

        slideShow.bind('showPrevious',function(){
            slideShow.trigger('rotateContainer',['previous',-90]);
        });
    }

    else{

        // Fallback for Internet Explorer and older browsers

        slideShow.bind('showNext',function(){
            $('li:first').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                $(this).remove().appendTo(ul).show();
                updateZindex();
            });
        });

        slideShow.bind('showPrevious',function(){
            var liLast = $('li:last').hide().remove().prependTo(ul);
            updateZindex();
            liLast.fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }

    // Listening for clicks on the arrows, and
    // triggering the appropriate event.

    $('#previousLink').click(function(){
        if(slideShow.is(':animated')){
            return false;
        }

        slideShow.trigger('showPrevious');
        return false;
    });

    $('#nextLink').click(function(){
        if(slideShow.is(':animated')){
            return false;
        }

        slideShow.trigger('showNext');
        return false;
    });

    // This function updates the z-index properties.
    function updateZindex(){

        // The CSS method can take a function as its second argument.
        // i is the zero-based index of the element.

        ul.find('li').css('z-index',function(i){
            return cnt-i;
        });
    }

});
```

the `var slideShow` gets referenced all over the script, I was thinking of using an onclick but this would be better if it was wrapped in a function and called on the go for all classes with a name.

Here's the html

```
<div id="slideShowContainer">

    <div id="slideShow">

        <ul>
            <li><img src="img/photos/1.jpg" width="100%" alt="Fish" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/photos/2.jpg" width="100%" alt="Ancient" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/photos/3.jpg" width="100%" alt="Industry" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/photos/4.jpg" width="100%" alt="Rain" /></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <a id="previousLink" href="#">&raquo;</a>
    <a id="nextLink" href="#">&laquo;</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one easy solution is to use a wrap all galleries in an element, then use classes instead of IDs to target them like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.slide-container').each(function() {
    var slideShow = $('.slide-show', this),
      ul = slideShow.find('ul'),
      li = ul.find('li'),
      cnt = li.length;

    // As the images are positioned absolutely, the last image will be shown on top.
    // This is why we force them in the correct order by assigning z-indexes:

    updateZindex();

    if ($.support.transform) {

      // Modern browsers with support for css3 transformations

      li.find('img').css('rotate', function(i) {
        // Rotating the images counterclockwise
        return (-90 * i) + 'deg';
      });

      // Binding a custom event. the direction and degrees parameters
      // are passed when the event is triggered later on in the code.

      slideShow.bind('rotateContainer', function(e, direction, degrees) {

        // Enlarging the slideshow and photo:

        slideShow.animate({
          width: 510,
          height: 510,
          marginTop: 0,
          marginLeft: 0
        }, 'fast', function() {

          if (direction == 'next') {

            // Moving the topmost image containing Li at
            // the bottom after a fadeOut animation

            ul.find('li:first').fadeOut('slow', function() {
              $(this).remove().appendTo(ul).show();
              updateZindex();
            });
          } else {

            // Showing the bottomost Li element on top 
            // with a fade in animation. Notice that we are
            // updating the z-indexes.

            var liLast = ul.find('li:last').hide().remove().prependTo(ul);
            updateZindex();
            liLast.fadeIn('slow');
          }

          // Rotating the slideShow. css('rotate') gives us the
          // current rotation in radians. We are converting it to
          // degress so we can add 90 or -90 to rotate it to its new value.

          slideShow.animate({
            rotate: Math.round($.rotate.radToDeg(slideShow.css('rotate')) + degrees) + 'deg'
          }, 'slow').animate({
            width: 490,
            height: 490,
            marginTop: 10,
            marginLeft: 10
          }, 'fast');
        });
      });

      // By triggering the custom events below, we can 
      // show the previous / next images in the slideshow.

      slideShow.bind('showNext', function() {
        slideShow.trigger('rotateContainer', ['next', 90]);
      });

      slideShow.bind('showPrevious', function() {
        slideShow.trigger('rotateContainer', ['previous', -90]);
      });
    } else {

      // Fallback for Internet Explorer and older browsers

      slideShow.bind('showNext', function() {
        ul.find('li:first').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $(this).remove().appendTo(ul).show();
          updateZindex();
        });
      });

      slideShow.bind('showPrevious', function() {
        var liLast = ul.find('li:last').hide().remove().prependTo(ul);
        updateZindex();
        liLast.fadeIn('slow');
      });
    }

    // Listening for clicks on the arrows, and
    // triggering the appropriate event.

    $('.previous', this).click(function() {
      if (slideShow.is(':animated')) {
        return false;
      }

      slideShow.trigger('showPrevious');
      return false;
    });

    $('.next', this).click(function() {
      if (slideShow.is(':animated')) {
        return false;
      }

      slideShow.trigger('showNext');
      return false;
    });

    // This function updates the z-index properties.
    function updateZindex() {

      // The CSS method can take a function as its second argument.
      // i is the zero-based index of the element.

      ul.find('li').css('z-index', function(i) {
        return cnt - i;
      });
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide-show">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="img/photos/1.jpg" width="100%" alt="Fish" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/photos/2.jpg" width="100%" alt="Ancient" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/photos/3.jpg" width="100%" alt="Industry" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/photos/4.jpg" width="100%" alt="Rain" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="previous" href="#">&raquo;</a>
  <a class="next" href="#">&laquo;</a>
</div>

<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide-show">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="img/photos/1.jpg" width="100%" alt="Fish" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/photos/2.jpg" width="100%" alt="Ancient" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/photos/3.jpg" width="100%" alt="Industry" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/photos/4.jpg" width="100%" alt="Rain" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="previous" href="#">&raquo;</a>
  <a class="next" href="#">&laquo;</a>
</div>
```